# How can I use jQuery to move multiple instances of a div?

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to move `p.read-emails` right after `p.download` for each instance it shows (on the same page) like this:

```
<div class="episode">
   <h3>title</h3>
   <iframe></iframe>
   <p class="download"></p>
   <p class="date"></p>               <--- TO HERE--
   <p class="artist"></p>                          |
</div>                                             |
<p class="read-emails"></p>           <--- MOVE THIS

<div class="episode">
   <h3>title</h3>
   <iframe></iframe>
   <p class="download"></p>
   <p class="date"></p>               <--- TO HERE--
   <p class="artist"></p>                          |
</div>                                             |
<p class="read-emails"></p>           <--- MOVE THIS

<div class="episode">
   <h3>title</h3>
   <iframe></iframe>
   <p class="download"></p>
   <p class="date"></p>               <--- TO HERE--
   <p class="artist"></p>                          |
</div>                                             |
<p class="read-emails"></p>           <--- MOVE THIS
```

I've tried this so far but I can't get it to work:

```
jQuery('p.read-emails').each(function() {
    var item=jQuery(this);
    var parentContainer=itemparents('.episode');
    item.remove();
    parentContainer.insertAfter('p.download');
    });
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('.download').each(function(){
   $(this).after($(this).closest('.episode').next('.read-emails'));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cYNL9/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
jQuery("p.read-emails").each(function() {
  var item = jQuery(this);
  var parentContainer = item.prev(".episode");
  parentContainer.find(".download").after(item);
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpg4M/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('p.read-emails').each(function(){
   $(this).insertAfter($(this).prev('.episode').find('.download'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like some diffrent use `eq()` selector

```
 $('.download').each(function(i,val){
      $(this).after($(".read-emails").eq(i));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S6Z4B/1/)